# Fourier transform giving wrong results?

Tags: fourier-transform

I have an equation $$xf(x)=f(x+1)$$ which is true for all real $x$.

Denote the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ as $F(z)$. Now perform Fourier transform on both sides, we get
$$\frac{i}{2\pi}F’(z)=e^{2\pi iz}F(z)$$

Solving the differential equation, I obtain
$$F(z)=C\cdot\text{exp}(-e^{2\pi iz})$$
Thus, 
$$f(x)=C\int^\infty_{-\infty} \text{exp}(-e^{2\pi iz}+2\pi ixz)dz$$

However, when I plug in $f(x)$ into the functional equation, it doesn’t seem right.

What is the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that the inverse Fourier transform of $\exp(-e^{2\pi i z})$ is $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\delta(n+x), $$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta. This certainly satisfies $x f(x) = f(x+1)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh no...I am expecting a ‘smooth’ function as a solution....

Comment: @SangchulLee Well, I am actually handling problems much complicated than this...anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: One way of interpreting your computation is that distributional Fourier transform cannot deal with your equation. This quite makes sense, since any tempered distribution is obtained by taking finitely-many distributional derivative of continuous functions of polynomial growth, while any non-trivial continuous solution of your functional equation grows factorially fast.

Comment: @SangchulLee Then would Laplace transform be able to deal with the problem? Also, it would be nice if you can provide more information about the polynomial growth vs factorial growth.

Comment: I do not think that Laplace transform is capable of dealing with functions of such fast-growing functions. (Notice that polynomial growth is always beaten by exponential growth, and factorial growth is even faster than exponential growth.) Perhaps it is best to share the exact problem that you are trying to attack.

Comment: @SangchulLee Actually, I would like to know the (intuitive and mathematical) reasons that Fourier transform can only handle function with polynomial growth. Please add it to your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{C} = \{ \varphi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) : \varphi(0) = 0\}$.

- Fix any $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}$ and let $f$ by $f(x) = \varphi(x)\Gamma(x)$. Since $\Gamma(x)$ has only simple poles and they are cancelled by zeros of $\varphi$, $f$ extends to a well-defined smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying

  $$ xf(x) = x\varphi(x)\Gamma(x) = \varphi(x+1)\Gamma(x+1) = f(x+1). $$
- Conversely, for any smooth solution $f$ of the functional equation, define $\varphi(x) = f(x)/\Gamma(x)$. Since $1/\Gamma(x)$ is entire, $\varphi$ is well-defined. Moreover, this solves

  $$\varphi(x+1) = \frac{xf(x)}{x\Gamma(x)} = \varphi(x). $$

  Together with $\varphi(0) = f(0)/\Gamma(0) = 0$, we have $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}$.

This provides a 1-1 correspondence between the set of smooth solutions of the functional equation and the family $\mathcal{C}$.